# Get notified for file downloaded via Chrome custom tabs on on Android App

Tags: android, android-download-manager, chrome-custom-tabs

I'm using [chrome custom tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/custom-tabs/overview/) on an Android App to open a webpage.
Inside the webpage, I'm downloading a file.

Is there any way on Android, to get notified after the file has been downloaded ?

Any help would be great as I scanned through all official docs for 4 days, couldn't find anything.

Comment: Is the file being downloaded from a site that you have control of? This might be an interesting feature request, however, unlikely to be enabled for the cases where the developer of the app and the site aren't the same.

Answer (score 0):

Custom Tabs doesn't provide callbacks that will notify the host application of files being downloaded.

The best bet would be using something like Android's [WatchService](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/file/WatchService) to monitor the downloads folder. However, I haven't tested myself and there may be caveats.